# Retrieving toggle switch value from Settings bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, settings.bundle

I need to load different background images in first ViewController's UIImageView called background , depends on what settings is used for toggle switch in Settings Bundle.

In -viewWillAppear in ViewController.m

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id toggleSwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"];
BOOL boolToggle = [toggleSwitchValue boolValue];

// setting custom back for viewController
if (boolToggle == YES) {
    [self.backGround setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    NSLog(@"YES");
} else if (boolToggle == NO) {
    [self.backGround setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

I haven't warnings but i can't set image what will be used.

Any ideas to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your IBOutlet is wired up correctly and use [background setImage:] instead of dot notation.  If neither works, you have an issue with your logic or setting/reading of the userDefault value.

Comment: I'm fairly sure he does instantiate his view controller (unless objective c *isnt* a FIFO lang...?) in this method.  It's probably that he hasn't instantiated his background property.

Comment: I moved all custom code from here to -viewWillAppear in ViewController.m but nothing changed. NSLog shows that i'm everytime inside else if.

Comment: CoDaFi, i have an IBOutlet for this background UIImageView set in code and IB. Just checked

Comment: @CodaFi:  I thought that code was in appDelegate, I see it's in his viewController, I have edited my answer.

Comment: I checked one more time, everything in IB wired correctly. Code the same as I showed here, but everytime I have boolToggle equal NO, so only "2.png" loaded. Can it be mistake in id toggleSwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"];
BOOL boolToggle = [toggleSwitchValue boolValue];  , because toggleSwitchValue is type of id, and I turned it to BOOL?

Comment: Yes it could.  Please use NSLog(@"") to determine what bool values you are getting from what (id) values.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, what is the placeholder for BOOL for NSLog output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19488/discussion-between-alexey-and-hackystack)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that, if the view is loaded from a nib, you modify the view in or after viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Alexey viewDidAppear would likely work with no issues, although viewWillAppear would be more traditional.  Try setting a breakpoint before your if statement, and in the debugger type `po self.backGround`.